# Have a CALayer with many sublayers. When setNeedsDisplay is called on a sublayer, I get an invalid context error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I just rewrote my game to use core animation in an effort to make it faster. I have a UIView with a layer that contains many sublayers (the game "tiles"). The tile sublayers are actually CALayer subclasses that draw their own content using `drawInContext:`. When a tile is selected, for example, it needs to be redrawn, so I call `[tileLayer setNeedsDisplay]` and I get a bunch of invalid context errors. If I call `[mainView setNeedsDisplay]` or `[mainView.layer setNeedsDisplay]`, none of the tiles redraw. How can I get an individual tile (CALayer subclass) to redraw?

**EDIT:** From the very helpful comments, I was able to figure out the this only happens when the CALayer subclass is drawing an image. Here are the errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Here is the line of code that causes the errors:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds];
```

Is there another way I should be drawing an image in a CALayer subclass?

Comment: The invalid context errors usually occur when you're trying to draw something outside of the `-drawRect:` or `-drawInContext:` methods. Make sure you're not doing that anywhere.

Comment: Can you post the crash log and some code related to the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Animation doesn't know about UIKit, i.e. `drawInContext:` doesn't set the CALayer context as UIKit's current context. The `drawInRect:` method in UIImage draws the image on this current context. To manually push a context to UIKit, use `UIGraphicsPushContext()` and pop it using `UIGraphicsPopContext()` when done.

For example:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```